# What are the longest possible filepath character counts on different versions of Windows

Tags: windows, directory, directory-structure

I have a total character limit of about 15k in which I can list a set of filepaths and filenames. I would like to know how many filepaths I could effectively put in this character count list.

Comment: given that you need 1 char for ``\`` and one char for a dir name, 15k/2 = 7500ish max. `/a/b/c/d/e/f/....../` 7500 times

Comment: The answer, of course, is 42.

Comment: 0. The pathname limit for the [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) API call is 32k Unicode characters.

Answer (score -2):

The max length of a path is 260 characters... this is not version-dependent, so this would be a limit for all versions of Windows.

Yes, you can get more than 260 characters using the Unicode versions of the API.  But that's not a normal thing you'd find in Windows.

So, 15k/260 = 59

BTW: I recently read that Microsoft has planned to increase this limit on some upcoming NTFS version.

Comment: Unicode versions of the API are not only found in every Windows version newer than '95, they're the ONLY API that actually now exists.  (The ANSI version of each function calls the Unicode version, since that's the one that does the work)

Comment: Also, the `_MAX_PATH` macro has absolutely nothing to do with NTFS version.

Comment: However, all existing windows GUI apps still adhere to the 260 character limit.  Likewise the .Net framework still limits to 260.  That's what I meant by "not a normal thing"

Comment: *"all existing windows GUI apps still adhere to the 260 character limit"* - That's not true. *File Explorer*, as the most prominent example, no longer has a 260 character limit for file paths (at least on Windows 10, maybe 8, too). [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) targeting Win32 likewise never had a 260 character pathname limit. .NET imposes an **artificial** 260 character limit (probably for compatibility). The Windows Runtime (and the Windows API) does not have a 260 character limit. Starting with Windows 8, unlimited shell path handling function replacements have been provided.

Comment: Yeah, the File Explorer can *view* very long paths, but have you actually tried to use File Explorer to create a path that's more than 260 characters long?

Comment: I just tested the new Group Policy setting on Windows 10 build 14393 that is supposed to allow for greater than 260 characters for "manifested Win32 apps" (and UWP apps).  It does not have any affect on the normal Windows GUI applications.  So, you still can't use File Explorer, PowerShell, or Command Prompt to generate a path longer than 260 characters.